# ¿Cómo convertir este codigo de C# de palindromos recursivo a C++?

Tags: c#, c++

```
using System;

namespace App
{
    class Programa
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce una palabra y te diré si es palíndroma :) ");
            String palabra = Console.ReadLine();
            if(esPalindroma(palabra)) Console.WriteLine("Es palíndroma");
            else Console.WriteLine("NO es palíndroma");
        }

        static Boolean esPalindroma(String cadena){
            Console.WriteLine("Función llamada con => " + cadena);
            if(cadena.Length < 2) return true;
            Console.WriteLine("Vamos a comparar => " + cadena[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Con => " + cadena[cadena.Length - 1]);
            if(cadena[0] == cadena[cadena.Length - 1]) return esPalindroma(cadena.Substring(1, cadena.Length - 2));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Resulta que solo tengo experiencia en C++ y me preguntaba si podrían convertir este código a C++

Comment: pega tu código en forma de texto, no coloques imágenes

Answer (score 3):

> Resulta que solo tengo experiencia en C++ y me preguntaba si podrían convertir este código a C++

Por supuesto que se puede; es más: se puede traducir a cualquier lenguaje. Me sorprende que teniendo experiencia en C++ no puedas abordar el asunto por tu cuenta.

#### Detalles.

Hay diferencias entre C# y C++ a tener en cuenta para hacer la traducción.

- En C++ se incluyen cabeceras con la cláusula de pre-procesador `#include`, no se importan (aún) módulos.
- En C++ el punto de entrada es una función libre que **debe** llamarse `main` y que **debe** devolver `int` y puede no recibir parámetros o recibir dos parámetros de tipo `int` y `char **`.
- En C++ la escritura en consola y la lectura desde consola se realiza mediante objetos *stream*: [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) y [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), estos *stream* no incluyen saltos de línea  no ser que se incluya explícitamente.
- En C++ los objetos no son referencia a no ser que se indique que lo son explícitamente.
- En C++ el operador de espacio de nombres es `::` y la cláusula para usarlo implícitamente es `using namespace nombre;`

Teniendo esto en cuenta, el programa podría quedar así:

#### Propuesta

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace App
{
namespace Programa
{

bool esPalindroma(const std::string &cadena){
    std::cout << "Función llamada con => " << cadena << '\n';
    if(cadena.length() < 2) return true;
    std::cout << "Vamos a comparar => " << cadena[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "Con => " + cadena[cadena.length() - 1] << '\n';
    if(cadena[0] == cadena[cadena.length() - 1]) return esPalindroma(cadena.substr(1, cadena.length() - 2));
    return false;
}

}
}

int main()
{
    using namespace App;
    using namespace Programa;

    std::cout << "Introduce una palabra y te diré si es palíndroma :)\n";
    std::string palabra;
    std::getline(std::cin, palabra);

    if(esPalindroma(palabra)) std::cout << "Es palíndroma\n";
    else std::cout << "NO es palíndroma\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!! Lo que pasa es que nunca he usado C# y como estaba mas acostumbrado a C++, por eso desconocía las diferencias